# Mouse focus on JLabel

Tags: java, swing, focus, jlabel, mouselistener

I would like to know if there is any method to set focus on my `JLabel`.
I have a series of labels and i want to know if i any one of them is selected.

I suppose to use a `MouseListener` but don't know what attribute of `JLabel` is used to set the focus or saying in some mode that i am choosing that label.

Thank you everybody and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do you want to **set** focus or do you want to **detect** focus?

Comment: i want to detect if someone clicks on my label

Comment: Test with theJlabel.addMouseListener(....).

Comment: The question is why? What is it you are trying to do? Making a label focusable makes no sense

Comment: `I have a series of label and i want to know if i'm selecting one of them.` - what if a user tabs to the label. A user should be able to use a keyboard or a mouse when using your application. Advanced users will use the keyboard, beginners use the mouse. Maybe using a JList is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

To detect if someone **clicked** on your label, this code will work:

```
package com.sandbox;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class SwingSandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = buildFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Click me and I'll react");
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("clicked!");
            }
        });
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(new JLabel("This label won't react"));
    }


    private static JFrame buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the point of label.setSize()? The layout manager will ignore it anyway.

Comment: @camickr that was there for "historical" reasons.  I'll delete that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `FocusListener` to your `JLabel` so that whenever it receives a focus, its listeners will be notified. Here is a sample test.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JLabelFocusTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");

                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                final JLabel lblToFocus = new JLabel("A FocusEvent will be fired if I got a focus.");
                JButton btnFocus = new JButton("Focus that label now!");

                btnFocus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        lblToFocus.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                });

                lblToFocus.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                        super.focusGained(e);

                        System.out.println("Label got the focus!");
                    }
                });

                frame.getContentPane().add(lblToFocus, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                frame.getContentPane().add(btnFocus, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```